# Menu with categories in Wordpress (+ Twig/Timber)

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I am new to Wordpress so I'm sorry (and please let me know) if I'm missing out on something very basic/trivial.

I have a page which displays all posts (of a Custom Type "Content"). And I would like to have a menu with category items so that clicking a given category would display all posts in that category.

What I currently have:

```html
<!-- menu.twig -->
<li>
  {% for item in menu.items %}
    <ul>
      <a target='{{ item.target }}' href='{{ item.link }}'>{{ item.title }}</a>
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</li>
```

```php
// functions.php

// Code from the Timber starter theme
/** This is where you add some context
 *
 * @param string $context context['this'] Being the Twig's {{ this }}.
 */
public function add_to_context( $context ) {
    $context['menu']  = new Timber\Menu();
    $context['site']  = $this;
    return $context;
}

// ...

// Content Post Type
function content() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Content', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Content', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Content' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Content' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Content' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Content' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Content' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Content' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Content' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No content found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No content found in the Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Content',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Content',
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/' ),
        'hierarchical'  => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'content', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'content' );


// Content Taxonomy
function content_taxonomy_init() {
    $args = array(
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'content_taxonomy', array('content'), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'content_taxonomy_init', 0 );
```

I have categories displayed as expected but when I click on them, I'm routed to `{url}/content_taxonomy/a/` ("a" is an example category), and that page is empty. What do I need to do to get the page to display posts?

I've read everything I could find and as far as I understand this should be done automatically, without me needing to to configure anything (?).

**Idea**: As I'm writing this, I'm thinking maybe I need to create a .php (and corresponding .twig) file (like content_taxonomy.php) and specify explicitly that I'd like to get posts of a selected category… Please let me know if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to (minus the menu) would be to create an archive template for the custom post type.

Take the current wordpress `archive.php` template, copy this and re-name it to `archive-POSTTYPE.php` < Rename 'POSTTYPE' to match your custom post type. For you this would be `archive-content.php`

This, by default should create a custom archive page for loading your custom post type. You can also do this with Taxonomies and other post types.

In regards to the menu, you could create a function like you have above that displays the custom post type names or post type taxonomies that links to the 'archive-posttype' to display a separate page for each.

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/